# Examples of stable organic cations

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

What are examples of organic cations that are stable at room temperature, can be isolated and that cannot be easily deprotonated by $\ce{NaOH}$? My only guess are various compounds with tetravalent nitrogen (tetraalkylammonium, *N*-alkylpyridinium, *N*-alkylimidazolium, etc.).
Are there some other examples?

Comment: Peralkylated ammonium is being often dealkylated by NaOH. Tetraalkylammonium salts, or anion exchanging resins based on them, are said not be with OH- ions too long .

Comment: Check out organic superacids and [proton sponge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,8-Bis(dimethylamino)naphthalene)

Comment: 'Can be isolated' is rather vague. Cations obviously can't be isolated on their own, so I guess you're asking about isolating it as a salt—but salt stability will probably depend on the counterion. Does any counterion count, or do you specifically have something in mind?

Comment: Various trityl salts are commercially available e.g. trityl tetrafluoroborate https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/GB/en/product/aldrich/164577

Comment: There are a whole range of ionic liquids available https://www.tcichemicals.com/assets/brochure-pdfs/Brochure_R5058_E.pdf

Comment: I agree with orthocresol. And Waylander gave the commertially available compound with  simple carbocation. If you need a exotic one try [this](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/164623), which is also commertially available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjugate bases of some other stable cations, called **proton sponges** or **superbases**, is discussed [here[1]](https://core.ac.uk/download/62655280.pdf). Broadly, the compounds discussed have one or both of the following functions:

**1,8-diaminonaphthalenes.** In these compounds two nitrogen atoms are fixed into positions that allow a proton to be simultaneously covalent-bonded to one and hydrogen-bonded to the other (or symmetrically bonded between the two nitrogens), giving a conjugate-acid cation that may be weaker at redissociating the proton than water would be.

**Bis(dialkylamino)cyclopropenimines.** These have a structure similar to cyclopropenones, except the ligands on the ring carbon are all nitrogen atoms. The pi-donor character of the nitrogen atoms combined with the aromaticity of the cationic cyclopropenyl ring render the protonated molecule a strongly stabilized cation.

**Reference**

1. Lee Belding (2016). *Bis(cyclopropenimine) Substituted Proton Sponge Derivatives: Theory, Synthesis, and Applications*, Ph.D. thesis, Brock University, St. Catherine's, Ontario, Canada.